# databricks-connect, py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o342.cache

Tags: pyspark, databricks-connect

Connection to databricks works fine, working with DataFrames goes smoothly (operations like join, filter, etc).
The problem appears when I call `cache` on a dataframe.

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o342.cache.
: java.io.InvalidClassException: failed to read class descriptor
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$client53442a94a3$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:523)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ParentClassLoader.findClass(ParentClassLoader.java:35)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ParentClassLoader.loadClass(ParentClassLoader.java:40)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ChildFirstURLClassLoader.loadClass(ChildFirstURLClassLoader.java:48)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.util.ProtoSerializer.org$apache$spark$sql$util$ProtoSerializer$$readResolveClassDescriptor(ProtoSerializer.scala:4316)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.util.ProtoSerializer$$anon$4.readClassDescriptor(ProtoSerializer.scala:4304)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1857)
    ... 71 more
```

I work with java8 as required, clearing pycache doesn't help.
The same code submitted as a job to databricks works fine.
It looks like a local problem on a bridge python-jvm level but java version (8) and python (3.7) is as required. Switching to java13 produces quite the same message.

Versions `databricks-connect==6.2.0`, `openjdk version "1.8.0_242"`, `Python 3.7.6`

EDIT:
Behavior depends on how DF is created, if the source of DF is external then it works fine, if DF is created locally then such error appears.

```py
# works fine
df = spark.read.csv("dbfs:/some.csv")
df.cache()

# ERROR in 'cache' line
df = spark.createDataFrame([("a",), ("b",)])
df.cache()
```

Comment: have you passed required databricks libraries?

Comment: @Prabhanj I'm not sure what libraries should I pass, the java process looks like this so all necessary jars seem to be passed
```/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242.b08-0.fc31.x86_64/jre/bin/java -cp /virtualenvs/dFbOM9ck/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/conf:/virtualenvs/dFbOM9ck/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/jars/* -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit pyspark-shell```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue and I think a recent patch fixed it. This was seen for Azure, I am not sure whether you are using which Azure or AWS but it's solved. Please check the issue - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/52431